# android:facebook video sharing error

Tags: android, facebook

Below is my code to share video *Facebook* but not working properly.

```
Uri videoFileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                               , "/video/testing.mp4"));

Log.e("Checking video ","Checking video"+videoFileUri);

ShareVideo video = new ShareVideo.Builder()
        .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
        .build();
ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
        .setVideo(video)
        .build();
ShareApi.share(content,null);
```

It shows error like this.

```
E/VideoUploader: Error reading video chunk. 
    Expected buffer length - '576'. Actual - '8192'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when we are share video of size greater than 2MB, facebook sdk give this kind of error, Try to share video less than 2MB.